# Python BeautifulSoup getting KeyError for image src

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get product image url from this [page](https://thedankvape.com/product/ace-of-spades-dank-vapes/) . I am getting image src but aslo getting this error `KeyError: 'data-lazy-src'`

here is my code:

```
image = soup.select('img.attachment-shop_single')

for i in image:
    img = i['data-lazy-src']
    print(img)
```

python shell result:

```
https://thedankvape.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/ACE-OF-SPADES.jpeg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#56>", line 2, in <module>
    img = i['data-lazy-src']
  File "C:\Users\Mick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1406, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'data-lazy-src'
```

I am getting image src but why I am getting key error? here is HTML element

```
>>>soup.select('img.attachment-shop_single')
[<img alt="ace of spades dank vapes" class="attachment-shop_single size-shop_single wp-post-image" data-lazy-src="https://thedankvape.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/ACE-OF-SPADES.jpeg" height="800" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20600%20800'%3E%3C/svg%3E" title="ace of spades dank vapes" width="600"/>, <img alt="ace of spades dank vapes" class="attachment-shop_single size-shop_single wp-post-image" height="800" src="https://thedankvape.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/ACE-OF-SPADES.jpeg" title="ace of spades dank vapes" width="600"/>]
```

how to grab last src element image link `src="https://thedankvape.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/ACE-OF-SPADES.jpeg`?

Comment: It's possible that your initial query "soup.select('img.attachment-shop_single')" actually selects several elements, and some of them do not contain the "data-lazy-src" attribute. Can you share the page you are working on?

Comment: There are two images on that page with `class="attachment-shop_single"`.  The first one has a `data-lazy-src` attribute but the second one does not.  You're getting the key error on that second image.

Comment: Alex I added teh link. please see top of my question

Comment: @John Gordon how to avoid the error?

Comment: Check that the attribute is present before trying to access it.

Comment: @John Gordon Thanks. I solved it after specifying the first element in my css selector `soup.select('img.attachment-shop_single')[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, there are two `<img>` with class `"attachment-shop_single"`. The safest way is to select just one with `data-lazy-src` attribute:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://thedankvape.com/product/ace-of-spades-dank-vapes/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

img = soup.select_one("[data-lazy-src]")
print(img["data-lazy-src"])
```

Prints:

```
https://thedankvape.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/VAPE.png
```

Comment: can please tell me more about `_one`?? can we use _two, _three for select second or third object ??

Comment: @boyenec `.select_one` just select **one** element. `.select` selects multiple elements (so you need to iterate over them or index them - e.g. with `[0]`). If you want second, third etc. use `.select` with `[1]`, `[2]` etc.

Comment: can we use _two, _three for select second or third object ??